# Html Button selected by default

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a button **in this format** `<button>Title</button>` clicked by default on page load?

I tried the following:

```
<button checked="checked">Title</button>
<button checked="true">Title</button>
<button checked>Title</button>
```

None of them worked in this case. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you need to use ` <input type="checkbox" checked/>` for this purpose.

Comment: You want to click the button with javascript or you want to change how the button looks? Also, "checked" is not a valid attribute for button https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: What do you mean by _clicked_? `checked` has nothing to do with `clicked` (or button)

Comment: thanks, but I prefer this method if there is a way.

Comment: instead of clicking the button after the page load to take action, i want it to be selected or clicked by default.

Comment: I don't see a reason why it is down voted really.

Comment: Do you mean that you want some of the buttons on a page to stand out i.e. to indicate to the user that the button is active in some way?

Comment: I mean, if there are 3 choices as in this example, one of them should be clicked/activated by default on page load. I used the jquery solution offered below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<button id="mybutton">Title</button>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("mybutton").click();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, Youssef. it works. I guess this is the only way.

Answer (score 6):

**The question**

I am trying to find out what you want. In the title you say you want to have it 'selected' by default, but later you talk about having it clicked by default. I assume you mean that it should have focus, and not that the button should actually be clicked.

---

**Solution 1: Pure HTML**

You can do this in pure HTML, this is done like this:

```
<button autofocus>Title</button>
```

---

**Solution 2: Vanilla Javascript**

If you want better [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus), you can use javascript for this:

```
<button id="mybutton">Title</button>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("mybutton").focus();
 });
</script>
```

---

**Solution 3: With jQuery**

If you have jQuery loaded anyway, you can always choose to use jQuery. Note that adding jQuery comes at a high cost (85kb minified). jQuery allows you to write this:

```
$(function() {
  $('mybutton').focus();
});
```

---

**Testing these solutions**

To test these solutions, you can use this simple CSS code:

```
button {background: red;}
button:focus {background: green;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for a checkbox/radio button that is checked by default:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="radio" value="yes" checked />
```

Button being selected by default provides very little value as buttons are used to submit or post.

Comment: Im sorry... am i wrong? please someone tell me why my answer was down voted so I can edit it to be correct.

Comment: I didn't down vote it. thanks for your suggestion. I need a button solution.

Comment: I think that was downvoted because of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com try to update your answer...

Comment: Good to know! Thanks @ZakariaAcharki
I will never reference w3schools I guess.

Comment: I disagree. You can link to w3schools. That should no longer be a reason for a downvote as w3schools has improved over time (see meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com). The downvoters are just stuck in their ways. Ofcourse it is always nice to reference multiple sources. It makes your answer much stronger.

Comment: Thanks @JoostS. I will keep all of the recommendations in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `autofocus` property.

```
<button autofocus>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that witch clicked you mean having the button in a permanent pressed down state?

If that is the case then it is not possible unfortunately. Html buttons can't be in a permanently pressed down state.

If it is really just about doing a simple button click then it is easy to do with JavaScript - you could do an onload event and call the click method via JavaScript (there are millions of ways do to that - depending if you use any frameworks or not so I can't give you a good code snippet for that out of the box)